# ClassNotFoundException when trying to start a Service

Tags: java, android, android-service, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to start a Android service:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MetawatchServiceStatic.class));
```

And application crashes with `ClassNotFoundException`. **But** it's working perfectly **on second try** when application started again. And everything is fine until system reboot. After reboot I need to try start service twice, again.

I tried to start the service in another process using definition in manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MetawatchActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:process="com.Clusterrr.metawatch.gui" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<service android:name="com.Clusterrr.metawatch.MetawatchServiceStatic" >
```

And starting service on button click:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.buttonStart:
        try
        {
            startService(new Intent(this, MetawatchServiceStatic.class));
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

I can't catch this `Exception` because it's occurred in service process and it crashes immediately. But service starting perfectly on second click. On third and other tries everything if fine too. Until reboot or APK reinstall. But sometimes it's working on first try without any problems. I can't understand why.

Android version: 4.4.2

Logcat:

```
1995-1995/com.Clusterrr.metawatch.services E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.Clusterrr.metawatch.services, PID: 1995
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.Clusterrr.metawatch.MetawatchServiceStatic: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.Clusterrr.metawatch.MetawatchServiceStatic" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Clusterrr.metawatch-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.Clusterrr.metawatch-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2651)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.Clusterrr.metawatch.MetawatchServiceStatic" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Clusterrr.metawatch-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.Clusterrr.metawatch-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2648)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a [ClassNotFoundException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) here because of the difference between the `Service` declared in the manifest file, which is ***".MetawatchService"***, and the one you're actually trying to start, which is ***MetawatchServiceStatic.class***.

Make the two to be of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

If the service starts "after the second click" for the class `MetawatchServiceStatic` it's because the second click is not doing what you think. The button may have another listener or some change in onClick that allows it to call the correct service class.

Your manifest declares `MetawatchService` but in your button click you are trying to run 'MetawatchServiceStatic` (the "Static" at the end makes them different). That does not appear to be all of your code or the entire manifest. Services *must* be declared in the manifest to run.

If you name it correctly or find what is causing the second and subsequent clicks to work, you will solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I just copy pasted wrong part of manifest (there are two services). Fixed.
There is simple startService() call. The code is pretty simple. When service and activity on the same process application just crashes. So it can't "remember" first run anyway.